# Search stopped working in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2013

In Outlook 2013 the search hangs on "searching" and no results are displayed. It does this for all 4 email accounts connected to Outlook (all IMAP). It used to work. I tried rebuilding the index and it worked again but only one time. I tried rebuilding the index again and it didn't fix it again. I tried trouble shooting and it said it couldn't find anything wrong. Any suggestions? I'm running Windows 8 64bit.

Comment: Try creating a new profile

Comment: Has anything changed since the "last time"? Is your IMAP e-mail cached locally? The hanging you describe could just be searching of e-mail remotely which could take hours depending on the volume being searched.